# apache camel filter in xml. Passing parameters to Bean in xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am new at working with activemq and Camel.

I have these questions:

1. I have a bean and bean method, which are invoked by filter.

   ```
   <filter>
      <method ref="MyBean" method="CheckReceivedFilesByParameters"/>
      <to uri="direct:b"/>
   </filter>
   ```

   Method CheckReceivedFilesByParameters returns boolean value.
   The next route starts succesfully if true. How can I invoke route (direct:b) when false. And I want to do this with xml. I tried to invoke method outside  tag but with no luck.

   ```
   <to uri="bean:MyBean?method=CheckReceivedFilesByParameters"/>
   <filter>
      <simple>false</simple>
      <to uri="direct:b"/>
   </filter>
   ```
2. How can I correctly pass parameters to MyBean method via Exchange message. What is best practice?
   Right now I'm doing by creating headers and later in my method I get headerValues.
   Example in my xml.

   ```
   <setHeader headerName="RouteId">
       <constant>Test1</constant>
   </setHeader>
   ```

   And then getting header in MyBean method value.
   `String routeId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("RouteId", String.class);`

   Should there'is some more "elegant" way. Like passing parameters. Like in servlets?

   > request.getParameter("par1")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the two instances under 1. are direct:b the same endpoint in both instances, or should one be direct:a (to make the distinction a bit clearer).

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1)

The filter eip only routes if the expression is true, eg the method call returns true. So if the method call returns false, then the filter does not route to "direct:b".

Ad 2)

Read about parameter bindings

- http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html
- http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html

Answer (score 1):

1. It seems to me that you might want to take a look at [content based routers](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html), an enterprise integration pattern implemented by Camel.  Using the syntax `choice > when > otherwise` you can basically add `if > else` style functionality to your camel routes.
2. Unfortunately theres nothing more elegent than that, which I am aware of.  You could always provide your own util class / method to abstract away the ugly process:

```
public class ExchangeHelper{

  public Object getHeader(Exchange exchange, String header){
    return exchange.getIn().getHeader(header, Object.class);
  }

}
```

something like that I guess?